Pull up equipment
I am a college student and I will stay at my parents' for the summer, where I do not have access to a gym.
To practice pull ups I could go at my local park, where there are a pull up bar, which is slightly thicker than a regular one, therefore I feel like I cannot grip properly, and a set of "rings", which are not the wooden, circular ones you can see at the gym, but are instead metallic and rectangular.
Noting that I am quite weak and not used to ring pull ups, which one would be the best option? The thick bar or the weird rings?

Both.
It's good to do pull-ups with a variety of grips and equipment. The thick bar will improve your grip; the rings produce a different angle for the exercise. Alternate sets between the two, or switch between them on different days. The difference is small so try both for a few sessions and see if you have a preference -- if it's strong enough, just do that one.
